# Resharper Convert foreach to LINQ using extension methods

Tags: c#, linq, resharper

I'm using Resharper 7 and sometimes when  I'm writing foreach loops it suggests that I convert it to LINQ.
Problem is that I'm unable to find a setting where I can choose that LINQ is created using the extension methods and not in the form of LINQ query.
I know this should be possible because it used to work like that before with my old settings (I had to revert them to default because they got totally broken for some reason).

This is the foreach loop:

```
var idList= new List<string>();
  foreach (var entity in entityList)
  {
    if(entity.EntityPathOrNull==null)
      idList.Add(entity.Identity);
  }
```

This is how it is converted:

```
  var idList = (from entity in entityList where entity.EntityPathOrNull == null select entity.Identity).ToList();
```

And this is how I want it to look like:

```
  var idList = entityList.Where(entity => entity.EntityPathOrNull == null).Select(entity=> entity.Identity).ToList();
```

Question is, does anyone know where this setting is located? I searched and googled everywhere but was unable to find it.

Comment: I'm unaware of a setting for that. AFAIK R# converts to LINQ query first *if* that's possible. You can hit Alt-Enter again to convert the query into a LINQ method chain, though.

Comment: I didn't know that with second alt+enter you can create a method chain. That's a nice workaround if this setting isn't found, but as I said I think it used to convert to method chain by default before so maybe it is hidden somewhere in some config file.

Comment: Did you include the System.Linq namespace in your using statements? You will need to include that to be able to use the extension methods.

Comment: AFAIK the query syntax gets converted into method syntax at compile time anyway, so I don't see much point in this other than readability.

Answer (score 2):

This is the only way I know of to convert it from query syntax.
Maybe this can be made the standard action somehow. Elsewise you will have to call it manually or via shortcut.

[image]